# How to make an url available for registration in a public channel using laravel-websockets?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

How to make an url to any user listen to a websocket channel, like `wss://stream.exemplo.com:9443/ws/channel@event`?

I'm using the [beyondcode/laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) package and I can consume the channels normally following the docs, but only with a javascript library like echo. My doubts are not about the protocol or how to listen it with Echo, it's just about how to make the part of `/channel@event` public available to anyone start to listen to it in a website like https://websocket.org/echo.html without any type of authentication.

I can see in they code and in the generated logs that they always require an appId (cause the package is multi-tenancy).

The `FetchChannelController` find the channel by `appId` and `channelName`

```
class FetchChannelController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $channel = $this->channelManager->find($request->appId, $request->channelName);

        if (is_null($channel)) {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Unknown channel `{$request->channelName}`.");
        }

        return $channel->toArray();
    }
}
```

```php
public function find(string $appId, string $channelName): ?Channel
{
    return $this->channels[$appId][$channelName] ?? null;
}

public function getChannels(string $appId): array
{
    return $this->channels[$appId] ?? [];
}
```

But I expect a way that any user without anything more than channel@event can subscribe to the channel in something like https://websocket.org/echo.html

**[EDIT]**

I expect a way to make an endpoint that the website https://websocket.org/echo.html can listen to it. I have hundreds of events been broadcasted to a channel "news" for example. So how (using an endpoint, not the channel name in a javascript library) the https://websocket.org/echo.html will start to listen to this channel? Without knowledge of any appId of laravel-websockets, just with the channel name.

Comment: use laravel echo with a normal channel not private ?

Comment: create a backend event and make it implements ShouldBroadcast interface and on the    public function broadcastOn() method
    {
        return new Channel('yourchannel');
    }

Comment: @AhmedAboud And how are the user subscribing with a public url in this way? This suggested is just a normal public channel.

Comment: because you will be expecting /chat  route to fire a event in controller         UserJoinedChat::dispatch($user->id);

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/get-real-with-laravel-echo really great tutorial it will show you the public and private channels

Comment: @AhmedAboud I made an edit at the bottom of the question, like I said, I don't have doubts with the public and private channels, nor to consume with a Javascript library (I have a lot of channels, public and private, been consumed by the frontend), the doubt is just how to make the endpoint available to anyone without and appId of laravel websockets package.

Comment: i really can't 100% understand whats the goal but https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/advanced-usage/app-providers.html might help

Answer (score 0):

One thing is a **channel** `id` and another one a **user** `id`. The channel and app ids will be used for Laravel-Websockets to identify to wich app and channel the server will emit/listen events. The user id is helpful to check if the user is identified to access a protected (private) channel.

If you want to listen to every event, create a general channel and then, in your website subscribe it to this public general channel to listen to your desired events fired in this general channel.

---

### Update

Given your actual requirement

As I said in my comment, you could manage the url string to inject the to your Laravel Echo (or your WS front-end library) in order to make it listen to your events. Given an endpoint like this:

> wss://stream.exemplo.com:9443/ws/channel@event

You could:

```
$string = 'wss://stream.exemplo.com:9443/ws/channel@event';
$segments = explode('/', $string);
/** ['wss:', '', 'stream.exemplo.com:9443', 'ws', 'channel@event'] */

$url = explode(':', $segments[2]);
/** ['stream.exemplo.com', '9443'] */

$event_data = explode('@', $segments[4]);
/** ['channel', 'event'] */
```

So you have everything to connect to your front-end library (`appId` aside, as you said you will handle this on your end):

```
$wsHost = $url[0];  // 'stream.exemplo.com'
$wsPort = $url[1];  // '9443'
$channel = $event_data[0]; // 'channel'
$event = $event_data[1]; // 'event'
```

PS: Here I'm using the [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) php's helper.

Comment: But how to make an endpoint that the website http://websocket.org/echo.html can listen to it, I have hundreds of events been broadcasted to a channel "news" for example. So how, using an endpoint, that the https://websocket.org/echo.html will start to listen to this channel? Without knowledge of any appId of laravel-websockets, just with the channel name.

Comment: Laravel WebSocket uses the same API that Pusher does. If you don't specify an app id, how will Echo know from where to listen events? You sure need to provide your details in the echo config (`host`, `port`, `app-key`). Remember that Echo just need to know your public key (and not the secret) in order to listen to events so you can expose this data client-side.

Comment: Forget Echo in the frontend libraries, think about the https://websocket.org/echo.html website. If I put a public event stream url in they input, will start to work instantly, that's what I need. About the appId, If I can't override the Laravel Websockets interface, I can set the appId for the unique appId that the application has.

Comment: If you are gonna do that then: In laravel Echo set your `wsHost` and `wsPort` and just pass whathever you want as a `key` (`*`) because you will override this either way. This way you will manage to connect your frontend to your backend to listen to events in your general (`news`) channel.

Comment: You're still thinking about frontend and Laravel Echo (Sorry if I'm seeming rude, it's not my intention). Forget about frontend, forget about Laravel Echo javascript library, wsHost and wsPort. Think only about how to give an endpoint to the https://websocket.org/echo.html and they start to listen me, not my frontend (all frontend is done, with correct libraries and settings, etc.) If you put this link for example `wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/bnbbtc@depth` on the websockets.org/echo.html and click in the "Connect" button, it will start to work instantly. That's what I want.

Comment: What is the difference between the full `url` and the concatenation between `wsHost . ":" . "wsPort`? None. I'm telling you all my responses oriented on Echo because it was mentioned on your original post if I'm not wrong. I mentioned the app-id because it is a requirement in the LaravelWS library. I guess that If you expected a different kind of answer you should've explain it better (I'm also not being rude, just a friendly advise). Returning to the original question: As I said in the beginning of this comment you could explode the string to get those two values to injected them to Echo.

Comment: Thanks, so now that you take the channel and the event, what methods of Laravel Websocket package I have to call to start a handshake with the call made by websocket.org/echo.html? Override the TriggerEventController __invoke method? https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/blob/master/src/HttpApi/Controllers/TriggerEventController.php

Comment: Actually, (ignoring the part in which you will override the app-id) you don't have to touch Laravel WebSockets at any moment. Just configure it to be your broadcasting driver and that's all, the package will manage the app/channel/event for you. You just need to set up Echo properly, check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#receiving-broadcasts) of the docs.

Comment: You did not get that I don't need to touch in the frontend/Echo/node/npm, all the question it's all about the backend serving to third parties that I don't need to know :(. I don't know how to explain this in a better way.

Comment: Read [this](https://murze.be/introducing-laravel-websockets-an-easy-to-use-websocket-server-implemented-in-php) mate to understand how Laravel Websockets works under the hood. In the post they give details about the endpoints used, the flow and so on. You can also check the [Pusher](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/pusher-websockets-protocol#websocket-connection) one. Good luck, I'm done with this one hehe.